# invalid operands of types 'const char [26]' and 'LPSTR '

Tags: c++, string, winapi

My code is

```
string  str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
LPSTR lp = const_cast<char *>(str.c_str());
MessageBox ( NULL, "The selected folder is : "+lp, "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

And when I try to build it and run i get this error

> invalid operands of types 'const char [26]' and 'LPSTR'

Comment: `"The selected folder is : "+lp` - this makes no sense. There's no such `+` operation in C++. What are you trying to do by that `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate a `char*` pointer (obtained from your `string` variable) to a `const char[]` array (from your string literal).  You can't do that concatenation.

Also, the `const_cast` is not necessary.

You will have to convert one of the pointers to a `string`, eg:

```
string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
const char *lp = str.c_str();
MessageBox ( NULL, (string("The selected folder is : ") + lp).c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

Or:

```
string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
const char *lp = str.c_str();
MessageBox ( NULL, ("The selected folder is : " + string(lp)).c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

Alternatively, simply get rid of the `char*` from the `string`, you don't actually need it:

```
string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
MessageBox ( NULL, ("The selected folder is : " + str).c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

Or:

```
string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
string msg = "The selected folder is : " + str;
MessageBox ( NULL, msg.c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

Or:

```
string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
ostringstream msg;
msg << "The selected folder is : " << str;
MessageBox ( NULL, msg.str().c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

Answer (score 3):

`LPSTR` represents a `char *`-type, and string literal `"The ..."` denotes a `const char[26]`. You get the error because in your expression `"The selected folder is : "+lp`, you try to "concatenate" them with operator `+`, which is not supported for members of type `const char*` or `char *`.

Operator `+` is, however, supported for members of type `std::string`; So you could work around this by, for example, the following code:

```
string folder = "The selected folder is : " + str;
MessageBox ( NULL, folder.c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK );
```

Comment: The `const_cast` is not necessary, since `MessageBox` takes an `LPCSTR` (`const char*`) as input, not `LPSTR` (`char*`).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the second parameter of `MessageBox` in this line of code:

> ```
> MessageBox ( NULL, "The selected folder is : "+lp, "Bye!", MB_OK );
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You can see a string literal, i.e. `"The selected folder is : "`, which is a NUL-terminated C-style raw `char` array (the `const char [26]` part in your error message); and you are trying to *"concatenate"* it using the operator `+` with `lp`, which you defined as `LPSTR` (i.e. `char*`) in your code.

Such operation is *not* defined, hence the error message.

It's clear that your intent is to concatenate two strings, and print the resulting string calling the `MessageBox` API.

To do so, consider using a C++ string *class*. If you are at the Win32 API boundary, I think ATL/MFC `CString` is very convenient. Or, you can use a *standard* string class like `std::string`.

`std::string` (and `CString` as well...) conveniently defines proper overloads of `operator+()`, which make it possible to concatenate strings with a simple syntax, e.g.:

```
string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
string message = "The selected folder is : " + str;
```

At this point, if you want to pass your message `std::string` instance to the `MessageBox` API (which is a *C-interface* API), you can call the **`std::string::c_str()`** method:

```
MessageBox( NULL, message.c_str(), /* ... other params ... */ );
```

Note that this code will compile in ANSI/MBCS builds (which is an obsolete build setting; Unicode build has been the default since VS2005, more than 10 years ago).

In your case, the actual Win32 API that gets called is `MessageBoxA` (note the `A` suffix).

Your code will fail to compile in VS solutions that use Unicode builds; in those cases, you may want to use the explicit `MessageBoxA()` call.

---

**EDIT** Not directly related to your error message, but might be interesting for you to know: If you are using a recent Visual C++ compiler, you may want to replace `NULL` with `nullptr` in your C++ code, and you can use *raw* string literals to simplify the way you write your paths, like this:

```
// Was: string str = "C:\\Users\\mardare\\Downloads\\config";
string str = R"(C:\Users\mardare\Downloads\config)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add together a `const char[26]` (that is, your `"The selected folder is : "` literal) and a `char*` pointer (that is, your `lp` variable of type `LPSTR`, which is `char*`). Concatenate the strings first and then obtain a `const char*`, which you can pass to the function:

```
std::string str = R"(C:\Users\mardare\Downloads\config)"; //don't care about escape sequences, use raw string literals.
MessageBox(nullptr, ("The selected folder is : " + str).c_str(), "Bye!", MB_OK);
```